# Что делают части кода в NODE.JS

Tags: node.js

могли бы объяснить,пожалуйста, что делают последние 2 строчки кода:
А точнее что выводит в консоль предпоследняя,и что значит "прослушивание сервера"

```
var http = require("http"); 
http.createServer(function (request, response) {   
 console.log(request.headers); 
}).listen(8888);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {   
 console.log(request.headers); // вывод в консоль заголовки запроса 
}).listen(8888); // тут на самом деле сначала создание сервера затем объекту сервера указывают прослушивать порт 8888
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Цитата из статьи [Создание веб-сервера в Node.js с помощью модуля HTTP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-web-server-in-node-js-with-the-http-module-ru)

```
const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

В первой строке мы создали новый объект server с помощью функции `createServer()` модуля `http`. Этот сервер принимает запросы HTTP и передает их нашей функции `requestListener()`.

После создания сервера мы должны привязать его к сетевому адресу. Для этого мы используем метод `server.listen()`. Он принимает три аргумента: `port`, `host` и функцию обратного вызова, срабатывающую, когда сервер начинает прослушивание.

Все эти аргументы необязательные, но всегда лучше прямо указать, какие порт и хост должен использовать веб-сервер. При развертывании веб-серверов в разных средах важно знать порт и хост, чтобы настроить балансировку нагрузки или псевдоним DNS.

Функция обратного вызова регистрирует в нашей консоли сообщение о том, когда сервер начал прослушивать соединения.